# MySQL - trying to combine `GROUP_CONCAT` with `COUNT()`

Tags: mysql, group-concat

```
SELECT A.id  ,A.Prospect_Id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A.MYVIEW SEPARATOR ' , ') AS myview
FROM
   (SELECT id, Prospect_Id, CONCAT(Current_Status, '(', count(Current_Status), ')') AS MYVIEW     
    FROM prospectdata1
    GROUP BY Prospect_Id) A
GROUP BY  A.prospect_id
HAVING myview REGEXP 'PHONE_FOLLOW_UP.*DUPLICATE'
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: Please include sample data (in form of text not images), table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Add `Current_Status` to the inner `GROUP BY`

Comment: Don't link images, but paste the results as text instead, please. Then, don't reduce your request to showing mere code. Tell us in words what you are trying to achieve and explain your tables. It seems `prospectdata1` can contain multiple records per prospect and you want to show a prospect with all its statuses in a string where you also show the number of occurrences of each of its statuses. Then you want to limit your result to those projects, where at least one status occurs more than once. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by both Prospect_Id & Current_Status:

```
SELECT MIN(MinId) AS id
     , Prospect_Id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Current_Status, '(', SUM(Cnt), ')') SEPARATOR ' , ') AS myview
FROM (
  SELECT Prospect_Id
       , Current_Status
       , COUNT(*) Cnt
       , MIN(id) MinId
   FROM prospectdata1
  WHERE Current_Status REGEXP 'PHONE_FOLLOW_UP.*DUPLICATE'
  GROUP BY Prospect_Id
      , Current_Status
) A
GROUP BY prospect_id
```

Comment: thank you everyone...and special thanks you  The Scrum Meister .. it worked for me